# How do I refactor ArrayList<MyClass> into MyClassLIst?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have a project in Eclipse (Kepler), and I am using using the following in a quite few places

```
AraryList<Person> person;
```

and then

```
person = new ArrayList<Person>();
```

and even methods that return and take

```
 ArrayList<Person>
```

Is there an easy way to refactor ArrayList in to something like PersonArrayList that extends ArrayList?

I would like to be able to have some methods like

```
ArrayList<People> getAllWithPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) {

}
```

**Update:**
The underlying reason for my question was based on the following need.
I was maintaining a list of People objects in a ArrayList, but I decided
that I needed to have some functionality such as being able to search this list and
return one or more people based on some properties.
My original plan was to create a new class that extends ArrayList and add
the methods to that class.

My current thinking is to create a People class that has an ArrayList rather 
then extending ArrayList

I think this is the right approach.  Please comment if I am going down a bad path.

Thanks for all the comments; they really helped me think thru this (I am obviously 
an amateur at all this stuff, but it is fun learning)

Comment: i think that you should use List<Person> instead of ArrayList in method signature, and don't subclass if is not necesary, what is `People` ??

Comment: Why would you want to do this though, unless you want to add some custom functionality to `PersonArrayList`? If all you want is the convenience of replacing `ArrayList<Person>` with `PersonArrayList`, you're doing Java Generics wrong.

Comment: Yes I just want to add some functionality.  For example if I want to find all the Person with a particular property, I think i have to do some thing like:

Comment: Could be I am using generics wrong, I have not done that much java and I am just learning andriod, but yes I just want to add some custom functionality to ArrayList<Person>.  For example personOfInterest =  people.getPersonWtihPhoneNumber(phoneNumber);  I could loop thru and collect them but I would have to do that everwhere I need that functionality, right?

Answer (score 2):

```
class PersonArrayList extends ArrayList<Person>{}
```

Comment: Ok, so is there an easy way to replace all usages of ArrayList<Person> with PersonArrayList?

Comment: For the full effect, add constructors matching `ArrayList`s constructors. They can just call the respective constructors in the superclass.

Comment: @nPn In Eclipse, in the Search menu choose "File...", press "Replace" down at the bottom and go from there.

Comment: @Jason Thanks I think the search , combined with the above is exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

I don't see bad returning `ArrayList<Person>` may be better would be returning the contract instead of concrete implementation replace with `List<Person>`

And if you still want to have your own type then create a class like.

```
class People{

List<Person> persons;

}
```

But subclassing to a new `PersonArrayList extends ArrayList<Person>` **is a bad idea cause you are not doing nothing with it only give it a name**.

Comment: +1 It does make the code less clear, since now a person reading the code has to go find `PersonArrayList` to see what you are referring to. On the other hand, if you're coming from e.g. a C or C++ background where `typedef` is common, it may make sense to you.

Answer (score 0):

You should use like this

```
List<List<Person>> getAllWithPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) {
 //TODO: put code here
}
```

Comment: I do not think returning a list of lists from this method would accomplish what the OP is looking for.

Comment: @nachokk You're right, I didn't even notice that said `People` instead of `Person`. @Sergio: I downvoted your answer. If you edit it (even trivially), I can remove the downvote. Sorry about that.